# How to remove char 8236

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to parse some phone numbers, and I have a function to check if the parsed string is made up of only numbers or the + sign.

In some of them there is an hiden character of value 8236.

[image]
[image]

Comparing it against '\0' and '\u8236' doesnt work...

What is this character and how do I remove it?

Comment: Unicode character `U+202C` "POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING" character, in "general punctuation". (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm). Where do you get this input from?

Comment: I'm parsing a webpage using HtmlAgilityPack. Your link did help me to find the correct way to identify it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Maximilian Gerhardt who sent this link in a comment https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm

I was able to know that 8236 corresponds to character '\u202c'

So I did `str.Trim('\u202c')`
And it did work

---

**edit:**

The simple way to get the corresponding code is to convert from decimal to hex.

8236(decimal) -> 202C(hexadecimal)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but with character 8237, which led me to this post.

This corresponds with character `\u202d`.